# fusion tables from google script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-fusion-tables

I using this code in google script from request to google fusion tables
https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/samples/apps_script

```
function getGAauthenticationToken(email, password) {
  password = encodeURIComponent(password);
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://www.google.com/accounts/ClientLogin", {
      method: "post",
      payload: "accountType=GOOGLE&Email=" + email + "&Passwd=" + password + "&service=fusiontables&Source=testing"
  });
  var responseStr = response.getContentText();
  responseStr = responseStr.slice(responseStr.search("Auth=") + 5, responseStr.length);
  responseStr = responseStr.replace(/\n/g, "");
  return responseStr;
}

function getdata(authToken) {
  query = encodeURIComponent("SHOW TABLES");
  var URL = "http://www.google.com/fusiontables/api/query?sql=" + query;
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(URL, {
     method: "get",
     headers: {
          "Authorization": "GoogleLogin auth=" + authToken,
     }
  });
  return response.getContentText();
}

function test(){
  var email = "xyz@gmail.com";
  var pass = "xyz";
  var token = getGAauthenticationToken(email,pass);
  Logger.log(getdata(token));
}
```

but, how I can make the connection with OAuth 2.0 without user/pass ?

Answer (score 0):

Not oAuth 2.0, Apps Script only supports 1.0 yet. But you can use 1.0 normally with the Fusion Tables API. There's no need for user-pass info. Here's a function I wrote a long time ago to set oAuth om my UrlFetch requests to Google APIs.

```js
/**
 * Set up Google's oAuth authentication for UrlFetch
 * @retuns {Object} args to be used UrlFetchApp
 * @param {string} name oAuth service name, can be anything
 *     but must not repeat between different scopes
 *     recommend to use a meaninful name related to the scope
 * @param {string} scope google scope for oAuth
 */
function googleOAuth(name,scope) {
  var oAuthConfig = UrlFetchApp.addOAuthService(name);
  oAuthConfig.setRequestTokenUrl("https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthGetRequestToken?scope="+scope);
  oAuthConfig.setAuthorizationUrl("https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthAuthorizeToken");
  oAuthConfig.setAccessTokenUrl("https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthGetAccessToken");
  oAuthConfig.setConsumerKey('anonymous');
  oAuthConfig.setConsumerSecret('anonymous');
  return {oAuthServiceName:name, oAuthUseToken:"always"};
}
```

There's also a [notable library](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/notable-script-libraries?hl=pt-BR) now, linked on Google Apps Script site, that will automate even more things to you. Please take a look.

Comment: I use this name and scope : `fusion`  `http://www.google.com/fusiontables/api/query`, but I get `Server response: <HTML> <HEAD> <TITLE>Login required</TITLE> </HEAD> <BODY BGCOLOR="#FFFFFF" TEXT="#000000"> <H1>Login required</H1> <H2>Error 401</H2> </BODY> </HTML> (line 24)`

Comment: after you call this function you have to use the object it returns as argument of you urlfetch call, are you doing it? e.g. `var args = googleOAuth(...); Urlfetch.fetch(url, args);`